# How to Multiply using Expression in RDLC ignore if it has string or null values with visual studio 2013

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

Hi Im having a problem in multiplying the Fields if it is 1 field is string. For ex. Multiplying the Number*String I got #error answer, it should be automatically to 0 but in null values, I have a function correctly and the answer is 0. How to solve my problem?

Here is my code currently function with null values:

```
=Sum(IIf(Not IsNOthing(Fields!Unit.Value * Fields!Grade.Value), CDbl(Fields!Unit.Value * Fields!Grade.Value), 0)))
```

I have tried also:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Unit.Value>0 And Fields!Grade.Value>0, CDbl(Fields!Unit.Value * Fields!Grade.Value), 0))
```

but the same I got error in multiplying with Number*String.

I've got my screenshot here:
[image]

Comment: Anyone who could help me?

Comment: have you tried something like this IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!Grade.Value), CDbl(Fields!Unit.Value) * CDbl(Fields!Grade.Value), 0)